# Is Chime a real bank for immigration purposes?

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, airports, proof-provenance-of-funds

I need to be able to provide immigration officers with 3 months of bank statements and I don't know if they expect it to be a traditional bank like Wells Fargo or if it can be Chime.

Chime offers online banking accounts that are FDIC insured through its partner banks, but Chime doesn't seem to be a bank itself.

Comment: Will you get statements that show how much money is in your account and when you got money into or got money out of the account? And will it hold all (or at least most) of your money?

Comment: OK, so just download and print your statements?

Comment: @Willeke Yes but I am saying that immigration officers ask for bank statements and I am asking if Chime's statements are acceptable or if they have to be statements from an actual bank.

Comment: Um, it is an actual bank account at an actual bank.

Comment: @Michael Hampton So it is a bank backed by other banks?

Comment: Why do you think Chime is not a real bank? What is your definition of ":real"?

Comment: Chime isn’t a ‘real bank’ in the sense that it does not have its own banking licence. It provides its app-based services via FDIC-insured bank partners. If you can get statements from it AFAIK there’s no reason why they shouldn't be aceptable, alongside the typical evidence substantiating the source of transactions eg payslips

Answer (score 2):

The small print of Chime says:

> Banking services provided by The Bancorp Bank or Stride Bank, N.A.

I take this to mean that Chime is essentially a marketing front for those two banks, and that the actual accounts are managed by one of the two partners. If this is the case then your accounts will be treated the same as a Bancorp or Stride bank account. I use a Canadian bank with a similar relationship to one of the big banks, and everything about my banking has always been treated the same as the major bank it is partnered with.